# What is the best strategy for handling large file uploads with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, large-file-upload

I'm looking for effective strategies to handle large file uploads (between 10 and 40 mbs) effectively with Ruby on Rails.

Ideally I'd like to implement a progress meter and some sort of notification when the transfer is complete.

I have looked at modporter (www.modporter.com), but I'm interested to know if there are other libraries, techniques or best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of solutions out there. You can look up this one from the rails way:

http://www.therailsway.com/2009/4/23/uploading-files

Comment: I mentioned in my original question that I have already looked at modporter (the recommendation in the article).  I'm actually looking for other solutions.